# ng-model not updated for select drop-down list in angular ui-bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap, html-select

Please see the problem in action:
   [`Working Plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/4ImSiwjDNafw1IQeFHQr?p=info)

I have a web page for adding person info. It should allow add/edit/delete multiple addresses for the person.

1. There is an Add New Address button on the page which opens a modal dialog to enter address info.
2. Clicking on Add Address button in modal dialog adds this address to the addresses list in the page.
3. After adding an address, the user can click on Edit button to edit it. This is where I am having issues.

For some reason, while editing an address, the drop-down lists for Address Type and State are not getting updated with model values even though values are seemingly set and served.

I am using **angular 1.6.2** with **angular-ui-bootstrap 2.5.0** for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple remove `track by key` syntax from ng-options and everything will be fine.

`ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in $ctrl.statesjson"`  will be fine

see [working exmaple](https://plnkr.co/edit/Gb1BuDTIWC3HetB5DVj1?p=preview)

Comment: This works great! I would choose ng-options over ng-repeat because ng-options seems to provide more flexibility according to docs. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using `ng-option` as `ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in $ctrl.statesjson track by key"` so due to this key value pairs angular is not able to bind value from your dropdown.

Use `ng-repeat` instead of `ng-options` T

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    
    <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@2.5.0" data-semver="2.5.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script>
      (function (angular)
{

    "use strict";
    // make sure you define all dependencies in main app only
    // you need NOT define these again in dependent components
    var addPerson = angular.module('addPerson', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    // only pass required dependencies in the controller
    // just because you've defined the dependency 'ui.bootstrap' in main app 
    // does NOT necessarily require you to pass it again in the controller 
    // when you do not use it here
    addPerson.controller('myCtrl', ['appFactory', '$scope', '$filter', '$log', function (appFactory, $scope, $filter, $log) {
        
        // functions must be defined before they are called
        var clearPerson = function () {
            $scope.selTitleVal = "";
            $scope.fname = "";
            $scope.mi = "";
            $scope.lname = "";
            return (null);
        };
        
        // clear all entries
        clearPerson();
    }])
    .factory('appFactory', function () {
        return {};
    });
})(window.angular);
    </script>
    <script>
      /*
  Contains following custom angular components:
  1. addresses: Add Address button and displays the list of addresses added with Edit, Delete buttons
  2. addressModal: Modal dialog to add/edit an address
*/

// 1. Angular Component: addresses
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    
    var stmpl = '';
    stmpl += '<div><input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="+ Address" ng-click="$ctrl.open();" /></div>';
    stmpl += '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" ng-if="$ctrl.isShow">';
    stmpl += '  <thead>';
    stmpl += '    <tr>';
    stmpl += '      <th style="display:none">Address Type Id</th>';
    stmpl += '      <th>Address Type</th>';
    stmpl += '      <th>Address1</th>';
    stmpl += '      <th style="display:none">State Id</th>';
    stmpl += '      <th>Actions</th>';
    stmpl += '    </tr>';
    stmpl += '  </thead>';
    stmpl += '  <tbody>';
    stmpl += '    <tr ng-repeat="x in $ctrl.addresses track by $index">';
    stmpl += '      <td style="display:none">{{ x.addresstypeid }}</td>';
    stmpl += '      <td>{{ x.addresstype }}</td>';
    stmpl += '      <td>{{ x.address1 }}<br />{{ x.address2 }}<br />{{ x.city }} {{ x.state }} {{ x.zip }}</td>';
    stmpl += '      <td style="display:none">{{ x.stateid }}</td>';
    stmpl += '      <td><input type="button" class="btn-xs btn-info" style="width:60px" value="Edit..." ng-click="$ctrl.editAddress($index);" />&nbsp;<input type="button" class="btn-xs btn-info" style="width:60px" value="Delete..." ng-click="$ctrl.deleteAddress($index);" /></td>';
    stmpl += '    </tr>';
    stmpl += '  </tbody>';
    stmpl += '</table>';
    stmpl += '<br />';

    function tableRowController($scope, $uibModal) {
        this.$scope = $scope;

        // these are fields in modal dialog - format for json
        $scope.$ctrl.dataForModal = {
            addresstypeid: '',
            addresstype: '',
            address1: '',
            address2: '',
            city: '',
            stateid: '',
            state: '',
            zip: ''
        };

        $scope.$ctrl.title = "Addresses";
        $scope.$ctrl.addresses = [];
        $scope.$ctrl.isShow = false;   

        // below is how you call the dependent component 'addressModal'
        // +Address is button's click event is wired to this
        $scope.$ctrl.open = function () {

            $scope.$ctrl.title = "Add New Address";
            // read documentation for 'ui.bootstrap.modal'
            // open the modal dialog for Add Address
            $uibModal.open({

                // addressModal.init() - initialize the modal dialog
                component: "addressModal",
                //windowClass: "my-dialog",
                resolve: {
                    modalData: function () {
                        return $scope.$ctrl.dataForModal;
                    },
                    title: function(){
                        return $scope.$ctrl.title;
                    }
                }
            }).result.then(function (result) {
                $scope.$ctrl.result = result;
                console.info(result);
                $scope.$ctrl.addAddress();
            }, function (reason) {
                // addressModal.closeAddress() is invoked here - same as cancel the modal dialog event
            });
        };

        $scope.$ctrl.addAddress = function () {
            $scope.$ctrl.addresses.push({
                addresstypeid: $scope.$ctrl.result.addresstypeid,
                addresstype: $scope.$ctrl.result.addresstype,
                address1: $scope.$ctrl.result.address1,
                address2: $scope.$ctrl.result.address2,
                city: $scope.$ctrl.result.city,
                stateid: $scope.$ctrl.result.stateid,
                state: $scope.$ctrl.result.state,
                zip: $scope.$ctrl.result.zip
            });
            $scope.$ctrl.isShow = true;
        }

        $scope.$ctrl.deleteAddress = function ($index) {
            if (confirm("Do you want to delete this address?\r\nOK: Yes     Cancel: No")) {
                $scope.$ctrl.addresses.splice($index, 1);
                if ($scope.$ctrl.addresses.length > 0) $scope.$ctrl.isShow = true;
                else $scope.$ctrl.isShow = false;
            }
        }

        $scope.$ctrl.editAddress = function ($index) {
            $scope.$ctrl.title = "Edit Address";
            $scope.$ctrl.dataForModal = {
                addresstypeid: $scope.$ctrl.addresses[$index].addresstypeid,
                addresstype: $scope.$ctrl.addresses[$index].addresstype,
                address1: $scope.$ctrl.addresses[$index].address1,
                address2: $scope.$ctrl.addresses[$index].address2,
                city: $scope.$ctrl.addresses[$index].city,
                stateid: $scope.$ctrl.addresses[$index].stateid,
                state: $scope.$ctrl.addresses[$index].state,
                zip: $scope.$ctrl.addresses[$index].zip
            };
            
            $uibModal.open({
                // addressModal.init() - initialize the modal dialog
                component: "addressModal",
                scope: $scope,
                resolve: {
                    modalData: function () {
                        $scope.$ctrl.dataForModal.addresstypeid = "102";
                        $scope.$ctrl.dataForModal.addresstype = "PO Box";
                        return $scope.$ctrl.dataForModal;
                    },
                    title: function () {
                        return $scope.$ctrl.title;
                    }
                }
            }).result.then(function (result) {

                $scope.$ctrl.result = result;
                console.info(result);
                
                $scope.$ctrl.addresses[$index].addresstypeid = $scope.$ctrl.result.addresstypeid;
                $scope.$ctrl.addresses[$index].addresstype = $scope.$ctrl.result.addresstype;
                $scope.$ctrl.addresses[$index].address1 = $scope.$ctrl.result.address1;
                $scope.$ctrl.addresses[$index].address2 = $scope.$ctrl.result.address2;
                $scope.$ctrl.addresses[$index].city = $scope.$ctrl.result.city;
                $scope.$ctrl.addresses[$index].stateid = $scope.$ctrl.result.stateid;
                $scope.$ctrl.addresses[$index].state = $scope.$ctrl.result.state;
                $scope.$ctrl.addresses[$index].zip = $scope.$ctrl.result.zip;
                $scope.$ctrl.isShow = true;

            }, function (reason) {
                // addressModal.closeAddress() is invoked here - same as cancel the modal dialog event
            });
        }
    }

    angular.module('addPerson').component('addresses', {
        bindings: { title: '<' },   // two way data-binding
        template: stmpl,
        controller: tableRowController
    });    

})(window.angular);

// 2. Angular Component: addressModal
(function (angular) {
    var stmpl = "";
    stmpl += '<!-- MODAL DIALOG: Add Address -->';
    stmpl += '      <div class="modal-content">';
    stmpl += '          <div class="modal-header">';
    stmpl += '              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="$ctrl.closeAddress();">&times;</button>';
    stmpl += '              <h4 class="modal-title">{{ $ctrl.title }}</h4>';
    stmpl += '          </div>';
    stmpl += '          <div class="modal-body">';
    stmpl += '            <div class="row form-group">';    
    stmpl += '              <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ddlAddressType">Address Type</label>';    
    stmpl += '              <div class="col-md-10">';
    stmpl += '                <select class="form-control" id="ddlAddressType" name="ddlAddressType" ng-model="$ctrl.modalData.addresstypeid" ng-change="$ctrl.changeAddressType();">';
    stmpl += '                          <option value="">** Select Address Type **</option >';
    stmpl += '                          <option ng-repeat="(id, value) in $ctrl.addresstypesjson track by id" value="{{id}}">{{value}}</option>';
    stmpl += '                </select>';
    stmpl += '                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="ddlAddressType" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>';
    stmpl += '                  </div> ';
    stmpl += '              </div>';
    stmpl += '              <div class="row form-group">';
    stmpl += '                  <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Address1">Address1</label>';
    stmpl += '                  <div class="col-md-10">';
    stmpl += '                      <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Address1" name="Address1" ng-model="$ctrl.modalData.address1" type="text" value="" />';
    stmpl += '                      <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Address1" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>';
    stmpl += '                  </div> ';
    stmpl += '              </div>';
    stmpl += '              <div class="row form-group">';
    stmpl += '                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Address1">Address2</label>';    
    stmpl += '                <div class="col-md-10">';
    stmpl += '                  <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Address2" name="Address2" ng-model="$ctrl.modalData.address2" type="text" value="" />';
    stmpl += '                  <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Address2" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>';
    stmpl += '                </div>';
    stmpl += '              </div>';
    stmpl += '              <div class="row form-group">';
    stmpl += '                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="City">City</label>';
    stmpl += '                <div class="col-md-10">';
    stmpl += '                  <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="City" name="City" ng-model="$ctrl.modalData.city" type="text" value="" />';
    stmpl += '                  <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="City" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>';
    stmpl += '                </div>';
    stmpl += '              </div>';
    stmpl += '              <div class="row form-group">';
    stmpl += '                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ddlState">State</label>';
    stmpl += '                <div class="col-md-10">{{getValue($ctrl.modalData.stateid)}}';
    stmpl += '                  <select class="form-control" id="ddlState" name="ddlState" ng-model="$ctrl.modalData.stateid">';
    stmpl += '                          <option value="">** Select State **</option>';
    stmpl += '                          <option ng-repeat="(id, value) in $ctrl.statesjson" value="{{id}}">{{value}}</option>';
    stmpl += '                  </select>';
    stmpl += '                  <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="ddlState" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>';
    stmpl += '                  </div>';
    stmpl += '              </div>';
    stmpl += '              <div class="row form-group">';
    stmpl += '                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Zip">Zip</label>';
    stmpl += '                <div class="col-md-10">';
    stmpl += '                  <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Zip" name="Zip" ng-model="$ctrl.modalData.zip" type="text" value="" />';
    stmpl += '                  <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Zip" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>';
    stmpl += '                  </div> ';
    stmpl += '              </div>';
    stmpl += '          </div>';
    stmpl += '          <div class="modal-footer">';
    stmpl += '              <input type="button" value="Add Address" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="$ctrl.addAddress();"/>';
    stmpl += '              <input type="button" value="Close" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$ctrl.closeAddress();" />';
    stmpl += '          </div>';
    stmpl += '      </div>  <!-- model - content -->';
    
    function tableRowController($scope, $http, $uibModal) {
        this.$scope = $scope;
        //var $ctrl = this;
        $scope.$ctrl.addresstypesjson = {"100": "Home", "101": "Work", "102": "PO Box"};
        $scope.$ctrl.statesjson = {"AN": "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "AP": "Andhra Pradesh", "AR": "Arunachal Pradesh", "DD": "Daman and Diu", "DH": "Dadra and Nagar Haveli", "DL": "Delhi"};
        
        // Events
        // 1. init - initialize
        $scope.$ctrl.$onInit = function () {
            $scope.$ctrl.modalData = $scope.$ctrl.resolve.modalData;
            $scope.$ctrl.title = $scope.$ctrl.resolve.title;
            
            if ($scope.$ctrl.title != "Edit Address") {
                $scope.$ctrl.modalData.addresstypeid = "";
                $scope.$ctrl.modalData.addresstype = "";
                $scope.$ctrl.modalData.address1 = "";
                $scope.$ctrl.modalData.address2 = "";
                $scope.$ctrl.modalData.city = "";
                $scope.$ctrl.modalData.stateid = "";
                $scope.$ctrl.modalData.state = "";
                $scope.$ctrl.modalData.zip = "";
            }
        }

        // 2. dismiss - cancel model dialog
        $scope.$ctrl.closeAddress = function () {
            $scope.$ctrl.modalInstance.dismiss("cancel");
        }

        // 3. close - add new address and close the dialog
        $scope.$ctrl.addAddress = function () {
            // assign selected text for drop-down list items
            $scope.$ctrl.modalData.addresstype = $scope.$ctrl.addresstypesjson[$scope.$ctrl.modalData.addresstypeid];
            $scope.$ctrl.modalData.state = $scope.$ctrl.statesjson[$scope.$ctrl.modalData.stateid];
            $scope.$ctrl.modalInstance.close($scope.$ctrl.modalData);
        }

        $scope.getValue = function(id){
            debugger
        }

        $scope.$ctrl.changeAddressType = function () {
            console.info("Address Type drop-down list changed");
        }
    }

    // register the component - dependecies automatically follow from app (parent)
    angular.module('addPerson').component('addressModal', {
        bindings: {
            title: '<',
            modalInstance: "<",
            resolve: "<"
        },   // two way data-binding
        template: stmpl,
        controller: tableRowController
    });
})(window.angular);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Add New Person</h2>
    <hr />
    <form action="#">
      <div class="form-horizontal"  ng-app="addPerson" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Title_Title_Title">Title</label>
          
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <select class="form-control" id="Title_Title_Title" name="Title.Title_Title" ng-value="selTitleVal"><option value="">** Select Title **</option>
            <option value="104">Dr.</option>
            <option value="103">Ma&#39;am</option>
            <option value="102">Miss</option>
            <option value="100">Mr.</option>
            <option value="101">Mrs.</option>
            <option value="106">Smt.</option>
            <option value="105">Sri</option>
            </select>
          <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Title.Title_Title" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Person_FName">First Name</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Person_FName" name="Person_FName" ng-model="fname" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Person_FName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Person_MI">MI</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Person_MI" name="Person_MI" ng-model="mi" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Person_MI" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Person_LName">Last Name</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Person_LName" name="Person_LName" ng-model="lname" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Person_LName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create Person" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:unset;margin:unset;">
            <div class="row" style="padding:unset;margin:unset;">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:unset;margin:unset;">
                    <addresses id="addresses1" title="'Addresses'"></addresses>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        
      </div>
    </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

[**Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/KYBSfl4wEmbWpMDMpT5B?p=preview) is the working plunker.

Comment: [using `ng-repeat` is bad idea when you have object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Comment: Works perfectly! Using ng-repeat should be ok in this case as number of options in each drop-down list is not too much. Thank you @Saurabh!

Comment: @sosspyker upvote and accept my answer if it works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but returned old string

```
  stmpl += '<option ng-repeat="(id, value) in $ctrl.addresstypesjson track by id" value="{{id}}">{{value}}</option>';
```

Also I found somewhere in your controller this

```
  modalData: function() {
        // $scope.$ctrl.dataForModal.addresstypeid = "102";
        // $scope.$ctrl.dataForModal.addresstype = "PO Box";
        return $scope.$ctrl.dataForModal;
 },
```

So, I commented hardcoded address

My [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/VVCr1wJnVW4u2GTSCRA3?p=preview)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thx!